# How to record video on Android into Stream

Tags: android, stream, media, mediarecorder

Android [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) allows to save video to file (file or socket):

```
setOutputFile(FileDescriptor fd);
setOutputFile(String path)
```

How to save videodata to OutputStream? It will be used for streaming video recording.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516018/android-localserversocket) Android-specific [LocalServerSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LocalServerSocket.html) seems to be the only possible way to get video data as stream. In brief, you have to:

1. create LocalServerSocket instance
2. set it as output file to MediaRecorder instance using file descriptor (mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(FileDescriptor fd);)
3. accept connection
4. read bytes from it (as from InputStream) in separate thread in loop

Another ideas?

Comment: Hint: this is not possible with new Android versions (I guess starting at 5.x)

Comment: @DenisLukenich why not?

Comment: It's quite some time ago. I think it got blocked due to more strict security measures.

Answer (score 14):

You can do it using [`ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html#fromSocket%28java.net.Socket%29):

```
String hostname = "example.com";
int port = 1234;

Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(hostname), port);

ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);

MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
```

If you prefer UDP, use [`ParcelFileDescriptor.fromDatagramSocket()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ParcelFileDescriptor.html#fromDatagramSocket%28java.net.DatagramSocket%29) instead.

[Credit](http://www.mattakis.com/blog/kisg/20090708/broadcasting-video-with-android-without-writing-to-the-file-system) where credit is due.

Comment: I knew it makes sense they would have included a way to specify something other than a file to receive the bytes, in setoutpuFile()

Comment: thsi results into java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 8090): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to localhost? Do you actually have something running on the phone/emulator that listens on that port?

Comment: I have setup a tcp server, whenever I do this I dont receive anything in the tcp server. I have checked the socket it sends the data fine and giving path also works fine. When I see the logs I see "/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -38"